# Problems Installing Gitolite on CentOS 5.5

Tags: git, centos, gitolite

Am hoping someone might be able to point out where I'm going wrong. I'm experimenting with Git and am trying to install Gitolite on my CentOS 5.5 development server.

I have been following a guide found here: http://www.atomcloud.co.uk/blog/creating-your-own-git-repository-server-with-gitolite/ which has been fine until it gets to the point of installing Gitolite.

The commands that the guide advises to run are:

```
cd $HOME
git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite gitolite-source
cd gitolite-source
mkdir -p /usr/local/share/gitolite/conf /usr/local/share/gitolite/hooks
src/gl-system-install /usr/local/bin /usr/local/share/gitolite/conf /usr/local/share/gitolite/hooks
```

Everything up to and including the mkdir line are fine. However when running the command

`src/gl-system-install /usr/local/bin /usr/local/share/gitolite/conf /usr/local/share/gitolite/hooks`

nothing seems to happen. I changed to src and tried running the command there without the src/ in front of it and I get the following error:

```
cp: cannot stat `src/*': No such file or directory
cp src/* to usr/local/bin failed
```

Beneath it advises the usage as being /usr/local/bin/gl-system-install however when running that it returns the same error.

I've tried Googling about for an answer and have found that the same batch of commands are also listed on the GitHub page for Gitolite, but I cannot see any reference to an error of this nature.

Obviously something I'm missing or a misconfiguration with my test server. I'm very much a beginner when it comes to the Linux command line so any help with this would be much appreciated.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

To debug this, I'd start at the src/ folder and run `ls` to make sure files in that directory exist. The error message you're getting suggests that no files exist inside the src directory although it is probably more of a path problem.

`/usr/local/src` is usually owned by root and your user account (not root) won't have access to write to that directory. Another thing to try is to run `sudo ./home/<youruser>/gitolite-source/src/gl-system-install` Where  is your user account name. This requires sudo privileges you might have to get from your sysadmin.

List any new error messages out here. Good luck!